# How to query in CouchDB using array keys which return exact value base on keys

Tags: couchdb

This is the scenario. 
Starkey=["2019-01-01","cola"]
Endkey=["2019-01-31","cola"]

I want to return all the cola from 1-31 of January in 2019 but there are return data that is not "cola"

Comment: How do your documents look like and in what context do you want to return all the cola (i.e. `/db/_find` command)?

Comment: emit([date,company],docs)
i think it's okay now. 
i change to emit([company,date],docs) im waiting for indexing in database and i will test this

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because you're querying a range.

For example, here's a possible view data. The matched range is delimited by the `---`.

```
| 2019-01-01 | abc  |
|-------------------|
|2019-01-01 | cola  |
|2019-01-01 | crush |
|2019-01-01 | pepsi |
|2019-01-29 | what  |
|2019-01-31 | cola  |
|-------------------|
|2019-01-31 | pepsi |
```

You can either index your view the other way around: [company, data] or use Mango view an index on the company.